# How do I sort specific questions to a specific section?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I fetched data from an API and was able to sort the large data received from the API into two arrays. An array called sections and an array called questions. So the sections array looks as such:

const section = [section-1: some_title, section-2:some_title, section-3:some_title]
and the questions array looks as such:

const questions  = [Q1-1:some_question, Q1-2:some_question, Q1-3:some_question, Q2-1:some_question, Q2-2:some_question, Q2-3:some_question, Q3-1:some_question, Q3-2:some_question, Q3-3:some_question]

What I want to do is merge both arrays together and sort them as such:
`const MergedArray = [{section-1: some_title, questions: [ Q1-1:some_question,Q1-2:some_question,Q1-3:some_question]},{section-2:some_title, questions: [Q2-1:some_question,Q2-2:some_question,Q2-3:some_question]},{section-3:some_title, questions: [Q3-1:some_question,Q3-2:some_question,Q3-3:some_question]}]`
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I just want to explain that Q1-1 belongs to section-1 and so do all the questions starting with Q1-x as indicated by the # 1 right after the Q. So, Q2-1 means the first question of section-2. So I know there needs to be some checks  happening to see what the first number is after the Q. Once identified it knows where to push the question to.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment added, I hope the structure for `section`, `questions` and `MergedArray` are as below

```
const section =  [
    'section-1:some_title',
    'section-2:some_title',
    'section-3:some_title',
];
const questions = [
    'Q1-1:some_question',
    'Q1-2:some_question',
    'Q1-3:some_question',
    'Q2-1:some_question',
    'Q2-2:some_question',
    'Q2-3:some_question',
    'Q3-1:some_question',
    'Q3-2:some_question',
    'Q3-3:some_question',
]
const MergedArray = [
    {
        'section-1': 'some_title',
        questions: [ 'Q1-1:some_question','Q1-2:some_question','Q1-3:some_question']
    },
    {
        'section-2':'some_title',
        questions: ['Q2-1:some_question','Q2-2:some_question','Q2-3:some_question']
    },
    {
        'section-3':'some_title',
        questions: ['Q3-1:some_question','Q3-2:some_question','Q3-3:some_question']
    }
];
```

Please find the solution to generate them below. I have added the comments for the code functionality.

```js
const section = [
    'section-1:some_title',
    'section-2:some_title',
    'section-3:some_title',
];
const questions = [
    'Q1-1:some_question',
    'Q1-2:some_question',
    'Q1-3:some_question',
    'Q2-1:some_question',
    'Q2-2:some_question',
    'Q2-3:some_question',
    'Q3-1:some_question',
    'Q3-2:some_question',
    'Q3-3:some_question',
]

const MergedArray = section.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    const node = {};

    const [key, value] = currentValue.split(':');
    // This will generate
    // key = 'section-1' and value='some_title' for first itration
    // key = 'section-2' and value='some_title' for second itration
    // key = 'section-3' and value='some_title' for third itration

    node[key] = value;
    // this will update node object as
    // node = {'section-1': 'some_title'} for first itration
    // node = {'section-2': 'some_title'} for second itration
    // node = {'section-3': 'some_title'} for third itration

    const sectionIndex = key.split('-')[1];
    // sectionIndex will be
    // 1 for first itration
    // 2 for second itration
    // 3 for third itration

    // Now you have to pick questions from questions array.
    // Questions For section-1 are 'Q1-1:some_question', 'Q1-2:some_question', 'Q1-3:some_question',
    // Questions For section-2 are 'Q2-1:some_question', 'Q2-2:some_question', 'Q2-3:some_question',
    // Questions For section-3 are 'Q3-1:some_question', 'Q3-2:some_question', 'Q3-3:some_question',
    // So you have to flter out the questions from the array.
    // `Q${sectionIndex}-` is string manipulation. This will generate 'Q1-', 'Q2-', 'Q3-'.
    // You have to filter out questions staring with these strings.
    // i.e, their respective index should be zero in the matching words from that array
    // The below expression will filter out questions starting with
    // 'Q1-' in the first itration
    // 'Q2-' in the second itration
    // 'Q3-' in the third itration
    const questionList = questions.filter((ques) => ques.indexOf(`Q${sectionIndex}-`) === 0);
    // this will make
    // questionList = [ 'Q1-1:some_question', 'Q1-2:some_question', 'Q1-3:some_question'] in the first itration
    // questionList = [ 'Q2-1:some_question', 'Q2-2:some_question', 'Q2-3:some_question'] in the second itration
    // questionList = [ 'Q3-1:some_question', 'Q3-2:some_question', 'Q3-3:some_question'] in the third itration

    node.questions = questionList;
    // This will update node as
    // node = {'section-1': 'some_title' questions: [ 'Q1-1:some_question', 'Q1-2:some_question', 'Q1-3:some_question']} in the first itration
    // node = {'section-2': 'some_title' questions: [ 'Q2-1:some_question', 'Q2-2:some_question', 'Q2-3:some_question']} in the second itration
    // node = {'section-3': 'some_title' questions: [ 'Q3-1:some_question', 'Q3-2:some_question', 'Q3-3:some_question']} in the third itration

    accumulator.push(node);
    return accumulator;
}, []);
console.log(MergedArray);
```

Comment: I forgot to add an important part to the section and questions array, they are all strings, so,  const section = ["Section-1:some_question"], "Section-2..."etc] also for the questions array

Comment: I have updated the answer wrt your comment. Hope this is the structure of section, questions and MergedArray. If not, please update your question.

Comment: Woww! You helped me so much! I got exactly what I was looking for Thank you --> Can you do me a favor and explain to me this line: const questionList = questions.filter((ques) => ques.indexOf(`Q${sectionIndex}-`) === 0); 
Specifically this part: ques.indexOf(`Q${sectionIndex}-`) === 0). What does it filter for when you are checking for "=== 0"

Comment: @PrinceMoMo Updated my answer with detailed comments in the code. Please check that. Please approve the answer if this s your requirement. Happy to have an upvote aswell

Comment: Thank you Nitheesh! Really appreciate it

Comment: @PrinceMoMo please approve the answer if this is what you are looking for

Comment: Nitheesh, can you elaborate on why you decided to check whether the indexOf === 0. I consoled.logged it but I can't seem to understand how it returns 0 or -1

Comment: @PrinceMoMo `ques.indexOf(`Q${sectionIndex}-`) === 0` this is because the strings 'Q1-', 'Q2-', 'Q3-' should be present and the questions should start with that string aswell. Which means index must be 0

Answer (score 1):

A generic solution:

```js
const section = [{"section-1": "some_title"}, {"section-2":"some_title"}, {"section-3":"some_title"}];

const questions = [{"Q1-1":"some_question"}, {"Q1-2":"some_question"}, {"Q1-3":"some_question"}, {"Q2-1":"some_question"}, {"Q2-2":"some_question"}, {"Q2-3":"some_question"}, {"Q3-1":"some_question"}, {"Q3-2":"some_question"}, {"Q3-3":"some_question"}];

let obj = {};

for(let ques of questions){
  let key =  Object.keys(ques)[0].split("-")[0].toLowerCase();
  obj[key] = (obj[key] || []).concat(ques);
}

let result = [];

for(let sec of section){
    let key =  "q" + Object.keys(sec)[0].split("-")[1];
    result.push({...sec, questions: obj[key]})
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the objects are as @Nitheesh set up, here is a way to get the answer with Object manipulation and the `Array.reduce()` and `Array.filter()` methods.

```
const reduced = Object.values(
      Object.keys(section).reduce((acc, cur) => {
        const num = cur.split('-')[1]
        acc[num] = acc[num] || {};
        acc[num][cur] = section[cur];
        acc[num].questions = Object.fromEntries(
          Object.entries(questions)
          .filter(([key, value]) => key.substr(1, 1) == num));
        return acc;
      }, {})
    );
```

I'll break out each step to help visualize what is happening

---

1. Create an array of the section object keys

```
const sectionKeys = Object.keys(section);
// [ 'section-1', 'section-2', 'section-3']
```

2. Using `Array.reduce()` create an object with the keys equaling each section number (steps within are included in comments)

```
const reducedObject = sectionKeys.reduce((acc, cur) => {

//Get the section number from the current value
  const num = cur.split('-')[1]

//Check if the key exists in the accumulator obj. If not return an empty object
  acc[num] = acc[num] || {}; //acc = { 1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {} }

//Get from the 'section' obj the value where the Key is the current value
  acc[num][cur] = section[cur]; //acc = { "1":{"section-1":"some_title"},
  //      "2":{"section-2":"some_title"}, "3":{"section-3":"some_title"} }

//Convert the 'questions' object variable into an array of [key, val] arrays
  const arrayKeyVals = Object.entries(questions); //arrayKeyVals = [ 
  // ["Q1-1","some_question"],["Q1-2","some_question"],["Q1-3","some_question"],
  // ["Q2-1","some_question"],["Q2-2","some_question"],["Q2-3","some_question"],
  // ["Q3-1","some_question"],["Q3-2","some_question"],["Q3-3","some_question"]]   

//Filter the array of arrays where the 2nd char of the key == the 'num' variable
  const filteredArray = arrayKeyVals
    .filter(([key, value]) => key.substr(1, 1) == num); //When num==1:  
  // [["Q1-1","some_question"],["Q1-2","some_question"],["Q1-3","some_question"]]

//Convert filteredArray back into an object
  const objQuestions= Object.fromEntries(filteredArray); //When num==1: 
  // {"Q1-1":"some_question","Q1-2":"some_question","Q1-3":"some_question"}

//Assign the filtered questions object
  acc[num].questions = objQuestions;
  return acc; //return the accumulator
}, {})
```

**Step 2 Output:**

```
{
    "1": {
        "section-1": "some_title",
        "questions": {
            "Q1-1": "some_question",
            "Q1-2": "some_question",
            "Q1-3": "some_question"
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "section-2": "some_title",
        "questions": {
            "Q2-1": "some_question",
            "Q2-2": "some_question",
            "Q2-3": "some_question"
        }
    },
    "3": {
        "section-3": "some_title",
        "questions": {
            "Q3-1": "some_question",
            "Q3-2": "some_question",
            "Q3-3": "some_question"
        }
    }
}
```

3. Now we no longer need the keys, so we get just the values

```
const final = Object.values(reducedObject);
```

#### Final Output:

```
[
    {
        "section-1": "some_title",
        "questions": {
            "Q1-1": "some_question",
            "Q1-2": "some_question",
            "Q1-3": "some_question"
        }
    },
    {
        "section-2": "some_title",
        "questions": {
            "Q2-1": "some_question",
            "Q2-2": "some_question",
            "Q2-3": "some_question"
        }
    },
    {
        "section-3": "some_title",
        "questions": {
            "Q3-1": "some_question",
            "Q3-2": "some_question",
            "Q3-3": "some_question"
        }
    }
]
```

---

I hope that this is not TMI. It took me a while before I could grasp the `Array.reduce()` method, so I wanted to break out the steps to hopefully help someone else that might need it.

Check out the working snippet below:

```js
const section = {
  'section-1': 'some_title',
  'section-2': 'some_title',
  'section-3': 'some_title'
};

const questions = {
  'Q1-1': 'some_question',
  'Q1-2': 'some_question',
  'Q1-3': 'some_question',
  'Q2-1': 'some_question',
  'Q2-2': 'some_question',
  'Q2-3': 'some_question',
  'Q3-1': 'some_question',
  'Q3-2': 'some_question',
  'Q3-3': 'some_question'
};

const reduced = Object.values(
  Object.keys(section).reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const num = cur.split('-')[1]
    acc[num] = acc[num] || {};
    acc[num][cur] = section[cur];
    acc[num].questions = Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(questions)
      .filter(([key, value]) => key.substr(1, 1) == num));
    return acc;
  }, {})
);

const pre = document.createElement('pre');
pre.innerText = JSON.stringify(reduced, null, 2);
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(pre);
```